# Gestureworks with AS 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am using gestureworks with papervision 3d on Flex 4, and i am using AS 3. I experience one problem, which is that i keep getting error in the line - container.addChild(cone), and it give the output which is 
"1067 : Implicit coercion of a value of type import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.Cone to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject"

May i know what went wrong?

public class TouchApp extends Application

```
                : 
                :
                :
```

public function TouchApp():void

{

```
 cone = new Cone();

 scene = new Scene 3D;

 cam = new Camera 3D();

 viewport = new Viewport3D(800,600);

 addChild(viewport);

 container = new TouchSprite();

 rendEng = new BasicRenderEngine();

 addEventListener(Event,ENTER_FRAME, gestCone);
```

}

```
public function gestCone(E:Event):void
```

{

```
  container.blobContainerEnabled = true;

  container.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN, downCone);

  container.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP, upCone);

  **container.addChild(cone);**

  addChild(container);

  rendEng.renderScene(scene,cam,viewport);

}
```

Comment: So is this the only problem? You have syntax errors, there should be no space in "Camera 3D" and "Scene 3D".

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because TouchSprite expects a DisplayObject to be added to it's displaylist, whilst you are trying to add a pv3d object "Cone" which does not inherit from the DisplayObject class... You can try to use container.addChild(cone.container) but I'm not sure that will work...

Comment: hey, Thomas thanks for your reply, it still doesn't work. and they gave me this output 
"Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at id.core::TouchObjectContainer/addChild() at WithTouch/touchCone()[C:\Users\080775b\Contacts\Adobe Flash Builder 4\WithTouch\src\WithTouch.as:50]".

Miha:Yep, that is the only problem. I didnt leave any spcaes inbetween Camera 3D and Scene 3D :)

Comment: I think you have to add your cone to the Scene, and then detect gestures some way else, by not using the TouchSprite class.. Here's an example with away3D (which is based on pv3d) http://gestureworks.com/flash-tutorials/multitouch-away3d-application/

Comment: how about if i have a .DAE format imported from 3D S Programmes? and also if i have other objects i have already done in my project that i used extends sprite class , will it be affected if i just import in away 3d?

Comment: forget to add, if i dont use away3d is that another option? as i find it abit troublesome to use away 3d when all along i have been using sprite classes, and furthermore i need to hand in my project soon